# Is it important to learn to find de period of the sum fo two DT signals?

Tags: discrete-signals, periodic, math

The fundamental period (N) of the sum of two DT signals could be the LCM of the fundamental periods. However, this is not always the case. I would like to know wether, during engineering design or engineering labor, it is important to know to find it (when it is not just the LCM)?
Can one always find N just by plotting? Or should one learn methods to find it mathematically.

Comment: It sometimes is useful/important. I've never seen anyone do that by plotting, though, and guess what, doing things mathematically allows a computer to do it for you, so guess what: If it's a useful technique to what you're doing, understanding the math will be immensely productive. But honestly, this question reads like a "should I be studying the math basics of what I'm about to do?" and you're asking this to a room full of signal processing folks: Yes. Yes, you should understand the math.

Comment: Thank you. Its just that, till the moment, i haven't seen my course/book getting to much into this (we only use for now LCM) so i was evaluating wether i should deepen into this topic my self or not.

Comment: well, I don't know what you study for what purpose – so I'll recommend what seems generally most logical: stick to the flow of your course; intensify knowledge when you feel a need, but make sure you're getting all the breadth that the course gives you. Getting specialist knowledge when having a solid, broad theory is easier than the other way around.